# trying to deploy React app on github pages

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, react-redux, github-pages

I'm trying to deploy a project using GitHub Pages however when I try to install the gh-pages package I get this npm error:

```
npm install gh-pages      
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: react-reveal@1.2.2
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @emotion/react@11.9.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/@emotion/react
npm ERR!     peer @emotion/react@"^11.0.0-rc.0" from @emotion/styled@11.9.3
npm ERR!     node_modules/@emotion/styled
npm ERR!       peerOptional @emotion/styled@"^11.3.0" from @mui/material@5.9.1
npm ERR!       node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!         peer @mui/material@"^5.0.0" from @mui/icons-material@5.8.4
npm ERR!         node_modules/@mui/icons-material
npm ERR!         1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!       3 more (@mui/styled-engine, @mui/system, the root project)
npm ERR!     peerOptional @emotion/react@"^11.5.0" from @mui/material@5.9.1
npm ERR!     node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!       peer @mui/material@"^5.0.0" from @mui/icons-material@5.8.4
npm ERR!       node_modules/@mui/icons-material
npm ERR!         @mui/icons-material@"^5.8.4" from the root project
npm ERR!       1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!     3 more (@mui/styled-engine, @mui/system, the root project)
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @emotion/styled@11.9.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/@emotion/styled
npm ERR!     peerOptional @emotion/styled@"^11.3.0" from @mui/material@5.9.1
npm ERR!     node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!       peer @mui/material@"^5.0.0" from @mui/icons-material@5.8.4
npm ERR!       node_modules/@mui/icons-material
npm ERR!         @mui/icons-material@"^5.8.4" from the root project
npm ERR!       1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!     peerOptional @emotion/styled@"^11.3.0" from @mui/styled-engine@5.8.7
npm ERR!     node_modules/@mui/styled-engine
npm ERR!       @mui/styled-engine@"^5.8.7" from @mui/system@5.9.1
npm ERR!       node_modules/@mui/system
npm ERR!         @mui/system@"^5.9.1" from @mui/material@5.9.1
npm ERR!         node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!     2 more (@mui/system, the root project)
npm ERR!   16 more (@mui/base, @mui/icons-material, @mui/material, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^15.3.0 || ^16.0.0" from react-reveal@1.2.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react-reveal
npm ERR!   react-reveal@"^1.2.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^15.3.0 || ^16.0.0" from react-reveal@1.2.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-reveal
npm ERR!     react-reveal@"^1.2.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/joshuaramat/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/joshuaramat/.npm/_logs/2022-07-18T22_17_54_773Z-debug-0.log
```

I'm happy to provide more details, however, I'm not sure how to proceed, I tried reinstalling react and tried to update react and react-dom to get the same result. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `react-reveal` hasn't been updated for 4 years, are you sure you want to use it?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski yeah, it's what I'm familiar with and if react-reveal is what's causing the error, then I'm happy to try a better solution!